# Grails: how do I check if field-being-validated was already added to a different Domain class?

Tags: grails, groovy, junit, validation, missingmethodexception

I have a Domain class of NameAndAddress. Each one can be a Musician or a CommunityMember, but should not be both.

```
class NameAndAddress {
    ...
}

class Musician {
    NameAndAddress nameAndAddress
}

class CommunityMember {
    NameAndAddress nameAndAddress
}
```

I want to add a validator to both of them, checking the above rule. I start with Musician:

```
class Musician {
    NameAndAddress nameAndAddress

    static constraints = {
        nameAndAddress(validator: { thisField ->
            return (CommunityMember.findByNameAndAddress(thisField) == null) ? true : false
        })
    }
}
```

When I run validate() on a Musician though I get:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: CommunityMember.findByNameAndAddress() is applicable for argument types: (NameAndAddress) values: [NameAndAddress : 1]
Possible solutions: findByNameAndAddress([Ljava.lang.Object;)
```

I don't understand the error. Isn't it saying a NameAndAddress object is invalid to give to something expecting... a NameAndAddress object??

What do I do to get this working?

---

**Edit:**
*(workaround)*- Still not working using above method. I have a ugly workaround that @sudhir pointed out gives a performance hit. This code DOES work though, if it helps people understand what I'm trying to do in a cleaner way:

```
nameAndAddress(validator: { thisField, thisObject ->
    boolean notACommunityMember = true

    for (CommunityMember communityMember : CommunityMember.list()) {
        if (communityMember.getNameAndAddress().getId() == thisField.getId()) {
            notACommunityMember = false
            break
        }
    }

    return notACommunityMember
})
```

---

**Edit2:**
*(The unit test code calling validate, requested by comments)*-

```
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
class MusicianTest ...

    NameAndAddress aNameAndAddress = new NameAndAddress()

    mockDomain(CommunityMember, [
        [nameAndAddress: aNameAndAddress]
    ])

    Musician musician = new Musician(nameAndAddress: aNameAndAddress)

    musician.validate()
    assert musician.errors["nameAndAddress"] != null
```

Comment: Rather then iterating over the list of CommunityMember (which would be a performance hit) - why don't you just do if(CommunityMember.findByPerson(this)) {notACommunityMember}

Comment: Thank you! That is a much better way to do the check. I was up too late last night and that makes obvious sense now.

Comment: I'm still getting the error, but I'm pretty sure it has to do with me Mocking incorrectly in my Test class

Comment: @sudhir I edited the above question. The code now uses your method instead of iterating. I updated with the new error I get, which now gives more info than the original error

Comment: If it is an unit test - you will have to mockDomain(CommunityMember) - I assume your test setup is doing this

Comment: Thanks for the help @sudhir. Yes it's a unit test, and I did use mockDomain. Hopefully I used it correctly. I added my unit test snippet to the original question. The unit test is successful when I use my "workaround" code. MissingMethodException when I use the findByNameAndAddress(thisField) stuff

Comment: Earlier the issue was with findByPerson - now you are talking about NameAndAddress -its confusing me..

And You probably can't have predicates in your member variable name
So properties like NameAndAdress or NameOrAddress will not work.

Comment: You just made my day. "And" in the Domain class name was indeed screwing things up. Thanks so much!

Comment: @sudhir I just realized you never got credit for this answer, since your replies were all here in the comments. Would you like to type a quick 1-line answer along the lines of "See comments on OP" or "See Bukov's summary answer", so I can mark yours as correct and you get the proper credit? :)

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Sudhir in the comments. Having "And" (or, assumingly, any predicate) in the a Domain class name will screw up Grails' odd little findByThenPutVariablesInTheMethodName syntax

Renamed class to NameAddress, and everything went great.

As an extra heads up to anyone doing this, be sure to use Grails' mockDomain class when doing a unit test that involves DomainClass.findByWhatever. I put my example at the very bottom of the question